# Access to Gmail API using service account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, gmail, gmail-api, google-workspace

I spent a whole week struggling with the Gmail API, but without success.

My task:

- create a mailbox with a custom domain;
- connect to this mailbox via
  Gmail API using service account.

What I did:

1. Created an account in Google Workspace and verified the domain by receiving a work mailbox with a custom domain:
   [image]
2. Gave the account the rights of the owner:
   [image]
3. Created a project within the organization:
   [image]
4. Created a service account in the project:
   [image]
5. Added a key:
   [image]
6. Added Gmail API to the project:
   [image]
7. In Google Workspace, I added delegation of access to data in the domain:
   [image]

However, I always get an error:

[image]

I think I missed something in the setup. I found that in some manuals it is indicated that after the step of delegating access to the service account is taken, when returning to the service account, such a check mark appears:
[image]

And after I do the delegation, my service account is empty:
[image]

What could I have missed in the settings?

Comment: Show the code that is using the service account. Your code must impersonate a user.

Comment: We humans are definitely social beings. And our strength lies in unity and mutual assistance. Sometimes even a little help or just a third-party view from the outside allows you to solve problems and move on to achievements. It was a retreat.


@JohnHanley, thank you very much! Your leading question made me think and make small changes. In the end, everything worked! Thanks again, I've wasted a lot of time and nerves trying to figure everything out on my own.

Comment: Glad I could help. Не за что

Answer (score 0):

Posting this for documentation purposes.

It's not enough to give domain-wide authority to the service account. You have to use that authority to actually impersonate a regular account in the domain; otherwise, the service account acts as itself.

#### Reference:

- [Preparing to make an authorized API call](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account?hl=sr#authorizingrequests)